# Flair NER Metrics interpretation

Tags: nlp, metrics, named-entity-recognition, flair

I'm currently preparing a NER Task with Flair and I'm looking for some information about metrics used for NER task.

What are the most used metrics and how to interpretate them ?

Comment: Would the [paper behind Flair](http://alanakbik.github.io/papers/coling2018.pdf) be anything close to an answer, specifically the evaluation section? Also I think this might be slightly off-topic for SO, since you're trying to optimize towards specific metrics depending on your respective task setup and environment (academic/industry)... This can attract strongly opinionated answers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking [sklearn-crfsuite's documentation](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-sklearn_crfsuite.metrics)if you want out of the box implementation.

For interpretation consider your NER system as a multiclass classification system.